# SQL - How to group/count items by age and status on every date of a year?

Tags: sql, date, join, amazon-redshift, recursive-query

I am trying to build a query from multi-year data set (`tickets` table) of support tickets, with relevant columns of `ticked_id`, `status`, `created_on` date and `closed_on` date for each ticket. There is also a generic `dates` table I can join/query to a list of dates.

I'd like to create a "burn down" chart for this year that displays the number of open tickets that were at least a year old on any given date this year. I have been able to create tables that use a `sum(case...` statement to group by a date - for example to show how many tickets were created on a given week - but I can't figure out how to group by every day or week this year the number of tickets that were open on that day and at least a year old.

Any help is appreciated.

Example Data:

```
ticket_id | status | created_on | closed_on
--------------------------------------------
 1          open     1/5/2019     
 2          open     1/26/2019
 3          closed   1/28/2019    2/1/2020
 4          open     6/1/2019
 5          closed   6/5/2019     1/1/2020
```

Example Results I Seek:

```
Date (2020)    |     Count of Year+ Aged Tickets
------------------------------------------------
1/1/2020             0
1/2/2020             0
1/3/2020             0
1/4/2020             0
1/5/2020             1
1/6/2020             1
... (skipping dates here but want all dates in results)...
1/25/2020            1
1/26/2020            2
1/27/2020            2
1/28/2020            3
1/29/2020            3
1/30/2020            3
1/31/2020            3
2/1/2020             2
... (skipping dates here but want all dates up to current date in results)...
```

- `ticket_id 1` reached one year of age on 1/5/2020 and is still open
  (remains in count)
- `ticket_id 2` reached one year of age on 1/26/2020 and is still open (remains in count)
- `ticket_id 3` reached one year of age on 1/28/2020 and was still open, adding to the count, but was closed on 2/1/2020, reducing the count
- `ticket_id 4` will only add to the count if it is still open on 6/1/2020, but not if it is closed before then
- `ticket_id 5` will never appear in the count because it never reached one year of age and is closed

Comment: Pease tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...? Also, sample data, expected results, and your current query would all be helpful.

Comment: Thanks - added sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to build a sequential list of dates, then bring the table with a ‘left join` and conditional logic, and finally aggregate.

This would give the results you want for year 2020.

```
select d.dt, count(t.ticket_id) no_tickets
from (
    select date '2020-01-01' + I * interval '1 day' dt 
    from generate_series(0, 365) i 
) d
left join mytable t
    on t.created_on + interval '1 year' <= d.dt 
    and (
        t.closed_on is null 
        or t.closed_on > d.dt
    )
group by d.dt
```

If your version of Redshift does not support `generate_series()`, you can emulate it a custom number table, or with `row_number()` against a large table (say `mylargetable`):

```
select d.dt, count(t.ticket_id) no_tickets
from (
    select date '2020-01-01' + row_number() over(order by 1) * interval '1 day' dt 
    from mylargetable 
) d
left join mytable t
    on t.created_on + interval '1 year' <= d.dt 
    and (
        t.closed_on is null 
        or t.closed_on > d.dt
    )
where d.dt < date '2021-01-01'
group by d.dt
```

Comment: Thanks!  I get the error `"Error running query: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables."` though. The `generate_series` subquery is working and I'll keep working on troubleshooting. I'll report back if I fix it but please let me know if you have other ideas.

Comment: I did some more research and discovered the `generate_series` function is not fully supported in redshift.  I was able to fix the query by pulling from a subset of dates from a "dates" table that was available to me instead of using `generate_series` to do it.

Comment: @jdrunbike: it is not documented, but apparently at least [some versions of Redshift support it](https://dwgeek.com/redshift-generate_series-function-usage-and-example.html/). But indeed, you can emulate this with `row_number()` against a large table. I added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If ticket_id is unique then you can do this to get all ticket at least 1 year old

```
select ticket_id, created_on , status where status = 'open' and created_on <= dateadd(year,-1,getdate())
```

if you want to count number of ticket per month then

```
select count(ticket_id), month(created_on) , status where status = 'open' and created_on <= dateadd(year,-1,getdate())
group by month(created_on)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!  Wouldn't either of those options return the count of tickets that by month they were created that are now over a year old? That seems to be the results I am getting. I need something that returns how many year old-open tickets there were on January 1st, then how many there were January 2nd, and so on (some tickets may close from day to day, reducing the count, and some might reach a year or more of age on any given day, increasing the count). Does that make sense?