# SQL - How to group/count items by age and status on every date of a year - part 2

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, recursive-query

This question is similar to a different question I asked and had answered here: [SQL - How to group/count items by age and status on every date of a year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096111/sql-how-to-group-count-items-by-age-and-status-on-every-date-of-a-year/62101416?noredirect=1#comment109873063_62101416) but I can't figure out this new problem. I need help with a query to group the data from the example table below into the desired results below. The goal is to total the number of tickets in a given state, by group, at the end of each sequential date starting at a specified date and ending on the current date.

Example Data Table (tickets):

```
ticket_id | opened    | assigned  | in_work  | closed     | assigned_group
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1          1/1/2020    1/2/2020    1/5/2020   1/5/2020     Network
 2          1/2/2020    1/3/2020    1/3/2020   1/5/2020     Software
 3          1/2/2020    1/5/2020                            Hardware
 4          1/2/2020                                        Network
 5          1/3/2020    1/4/2020    1/5/2020                Software
 6          1/3/2020                                        Network
... and more continuing in similar pattern
```

Desired Result:

```
Date      | assigned_group | num_open | num_assigned | num_in_work | num_closed |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1/1/2020   Network          1            0              0             0 
 1/1/2020   Software         0            0              0             0 
 1/1/2020   Hardware         0            0              0             0 
 1/2/2020   Network          1            1              0             0 
 1/2/2020   Software         1            0              0             0 
 1/2/2020   Hardware         1            0              0             0 
 1/3/2020   Network          2            1              0             0 
 1/3/2020   Software         1            0              1             0 
 1/3/2020   Hardware         1            0              0             0  
 1/4/2020   Network          2            1              0             0 
 1/4/2020   Software         0            1              1             0 
 1/4/2020   Hardware         1            0              0             0 
 1/5/2020   Network          2            0              0             1 
 1/5/2020   Software         0            0              1             1 
 1/5/2020   Hardware         0            1              0             0  
... continuing to present date
```

Thank you!

Comment: just a curiosity: what happen on the 1/6/2020? Ticket 1 and 2 where closed on the 1/5/2020, you want them to still be count as num_in_work?

Comment: Ok, read the answer of Gordon and got me an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot and use a cumulative sum:

```
with da as (
      select opened as date, assigned_group, 1 as open_inc, 0 as assigned_inc, 0 as in_work_inc, 0 as closed_inc
      from t
      union all
      select assigned, assigned_group, -1, 1, 0, 0
      from t
      union all
      select in_work, assigned_group, 0 -1, 1, 0
      from t
      union all
      select closed, assigned_group, 0, 0, -1, 1
      from t
     )
select date, assigned_group,
       sum(sum(open_inc)) over (partition by assigned_group order by date) as num_opens,
       sum(sum(assigned_inc)) over (partition by assigned_group order by date) as num_assigned,
       sum(sum(in_work_inc)) over (partition by assigned_group order by date) as num_in_work,
       sum(sum(closed_inc)) over (partition by assigned_group order by date) as num_closed
from da
group by date, assigned_group
order by date, assigned_group;
```